# Deleted root folder and run out of storage

Tags: linux, dual-boot

I have a LM21 Dualboot system. After downloading some applications,I couldn’t do anything because I ran out of space. So I started to delete some files and ended up with deleting my whole root folder as I tried to reboot Linux it reboots me into a terminal where I have to give my username and password after entering those things I can use the terminal as usual but I am not able to get to my usual surface. Re-downloading applications like grub is not possible since I get the error that there is no space left. Unfortunately I have no backup so I try to copy my files to an USB flash drive. This fails because my flash drive is not listed.
Is there any other possibility to save my files or do I have to set up Linux from scratch again?

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you reinstall Linux Mint again.

To get private files, that is stored, you might be able to save them. Use your Windows boot to make a new Linux Mint bootable USB, and boot into this. Use the this to open your destroyed Linux Mint, and find your files. Saves those to a second USB drive. When done, you can reinstall Linux Mint.